# Pandas pct_change with Multi-Index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I would like to calculate the percentage change in a multi-index pandas df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2020-05-01', '2020-06-01'], 
                                        ['Device 1'], 
                                        ['Sub Device 1', 'Sub Device 2', 'Sub Device 3'],
                                        ['New User', 'Returning User']],
                                       names=['Month', 'Device', 'Sub Device', 'New User Ind']),
    data={'Users':[1011598, 1654645,   40917,  190305,   31284,   
                    61318, 1040834, 1577128,   29896,  156499,   
                    29133,   59622]})
```

I am looking for the pct_change for every combination of the four index levels.  This is what I have right now:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).pct_change()
```

but all I am getting is nulls in the user column.

[image]

Do I need to also include an `apply` after the `groupby`?

The final table should look like this

```
                                                 Users
Month      Device   Sub Device   New User Ind         
2020-05-01 Device 1 Sub Device 1 New User          NaN
                                 Returning User    NaN
                    Sub Device 2 New User          NaN
                                 Returning User    NaN
                    Sub Device 3 New User          NaN
                                 Returning User    NaN
2020-06-01 Device 1 Sub Device 1 New User         0.02
                                 Returning User  -0.04
                    Sub Device 2 New User        -0.20
                                 Returning User  -0.17
                    Sub Device 3 New User        -0.06
                                 Returning User  -0.02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using groupby, you were close, just didn't need to include level 0 of the index:

```
df.groupby(level=[1,2,3]).pct_change()
```

Output:

```
                                                    Users
Month      Device   Sub Device   New User Ind            
2020-05-01 Device 1 Sub Device 1 New User             NaN
                                 Returning User       NaN
                    Sub Device 2 New User             NaN
                                 Returning User       NaN
                    Sub Device 3 New User             NaN
                                 Returning User       NaN
2020-06-01 Device 1 Sub Device 1 New User        0.028901
                                 Returning User -0.046848
                    Sub Device 2 New User       -0.269350
                                 Returning User -0.177641
                    Sub Device 3 New User       -0.068757
                                 Returning User -0.027659
```

Comment: @Scott_Boston Thanks for your response. While the stack/unstack method does work, shouldn't it be possible to use the .pct_change() method directly with a groupby similar to .sum() or .diff()?

Comment: @Scott_Boston thanks!  Why wouldn't I include the first level in the groupby in this case?

Comment: @JamesD. Because you are taking the difference no matter the date, so you don't want each date to be in its own group.  You want to group by the other index levels and take the difference accross dates.